# Рекурсивный обход дерева в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, рекурсия

Не получается подняться вверх по дереву, хотя, на мой взгляд, всё вроде правильно.

```js
var array = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var liElements = $("#frontMenu").children();
  for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
    var object = {
      selfId: liElements.eq(i).attr('id'),
      parentId: null
    };
    array.push(object);
    recursiveGoToChild(liElements.eq(i));
  }
  console.log(array);
});

function recursiveGoToChild(liElement) {
  var olElement = liElement.children().eq(1);
  if (olElement.find("li").length != 0) {
    liElements = olElement.children();

    for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
      var object = {
        selfId: liElements.eq(i).attr('id'),
        parentId: liElement.attr('id')
      };
      array.push(object);
      recursiveGoToChild(liElements.eq(i));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="nested_with_switch vertical" id="frontMenu">
  <li id="1">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li id="2">
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li id="3">
    <p>Item 3</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li id="4">
    <p>Item 4</p>
    <ol>
      <li id="5">
        <p>Item 5</p>
        <ol>
          <li id="6">
            <p>Item 6</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="7">
            <p>Item 7</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="8">
            <p>Item 8</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="9">
            <p>Item 9</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="10">
            <p>Item 10</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="11">
            <p>Item 11</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li id="12">
        <p>Item 12</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="13">
        <p>Item 13</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="14">
        <p>Item 14</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="15">
        <p>Item 15</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="16">
        <p>Item 16</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="17">
        <p>Item 17</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li id="18">
    <p>Item 18</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li id="19">
    <p>Item 19</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Что должно было получиться в итоге?

Comment: Массив array, в котором лежат объекты. У этих объектов 2 поля: id родителя и свой id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли в рекурсивной функции объявить переменную `liElements` из за чего она автоматически становилась глобальной. Из за этого при вхождении в дочернюю ветку рекурсии эта глобальная переменная переприсваивалась, и родительская рекурсия продолжала работу с уже изменённым набором элементов.

```js
var array = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var liElements = $("#frontMenu").children();
  for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
    var object = {
      selfId: liElements.eq(i).attr('id'),
      parentId: null
    };
    array.push(object);
    recursiveGoToChild(liElements.eq(i));
  }
  console.log(array);
});

function recursiveGoToChild(liElement) {
  var olElement = liElement.children().eq(1);
  if (olElement.find("li").length != 0) {
    let liElements = olElement.children();
    //^---вот здесь небыло let

    for (var i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
      var object = {
        selfId: liElements.eq(i).attr('id'),
        parentId: liElement.attr('id')
      };
      array.push(object);
      recursiveGoToChild(liElements.eq(i));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="nested_with_switch vertical" id="frontMenu">
  <li id="1">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li id="2">
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li id="3">
    <p>Item 3</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li id="4">
    <p>Item 4</p>
    <ol>
      <li id="5">
        <p>Item 5</p>
        <ol>
          <li id="6">
            <p>Item 6</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="7">
            <p>Item 7</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="8">
            <p>Item 8</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="9">
            <p>Item 9</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="10">
            <p>Item 10</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
          <li id="11">
            <p>Item 11</p>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li id="12">
        <p>Item 12</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="13">
        <p>Item 13</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="14">
        <p>Item 14</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="15">
        <p>Item 15</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="16">
        <p>Item 16</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li id="17">
        <p>Item 17</p>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li id="18">
    <p>Item 18</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li id="19">
    <p>Item 19</p>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```